# How to trigger R code from excel?

Tags: r, excel

I want to trigger R code from an excel spreadsheet. I couldn't find any options other than [Rexcel](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/). Is there any alternative or simpler way to do this (may be use VBA)?

Comment: Close Excel, and start R. Go for it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VBA you can call any command line programs, so you can call R in batch mode.

```
Call Shell("R --vanilla scriptfile.R outputfile.txt")
```